# Setting span alignment inside button

Tags: html, css

i have two spans inside the button . Im trying to set one span ( which has text) to left of the button and other span ( which has caret) to the right of the button. But both the spans appears at the center. Can someone help

```css
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid #000000;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0 dotted;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";    
}
```

```html
<button type="button" style="width:300px;"><span style="text-align:left">selected all</span><span style="text-align:right;" class="caret"></span></button>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/887r8rav/

Comment: do you want like this? http://jsbin.com/sozequqaja/1/edit

Answer (score 5):

`text-align` won't work in your case because there is no any text for span have class `caret`. So you've to use `float:right` property, Now since we'll use the `float` property we've to clear the float as well; so child elements won't get affected./

To make align the caret with text you've to play with `position:relative` as well. No need to add inline CSS. Check [Jsbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/sozequqaja/1/edit)

```css
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid #000000;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0 dotted;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  float:right; 
  content: ""; 
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:45%;
}
button{display:block;width:300px; text-align:left; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}
```

```html
<button type="button">
  <span>selected all</span>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

**Update:**

You no need to add extra span in your code, that can be achieve just using one span tag and using `:after` pseudo element.

```css
span:after{ 
  content: ""; 
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:45%;
   vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid #000000;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0 dotted;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  display:inline-block;
}


button{display:block;width:300px; text-align:left; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}
```

```html
<button type="button">
  <span>selected all</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [css float](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDUQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2Ffloat&ei=AoZRVb-HJMytuQTUwIDYCw&usg=AFQjCNFpGD9jYnilk8wBiOeLUuVFGl6Nww&sig2=H10lls37vBmNtl7RwIRWbg&bvm=bv.92885102,d.c2E&cad=rja) property to align the elements respectively. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/887r8rav/2/)

```
<button type="button" style="width:300px;"><span style="float: left;">selected all</span><span style="float: right;" class="caret"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `float` instead of `text-align`

```css
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid #000000;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0 dotted;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";    
}
```

```html
<button type="button" style="width:300px;"><span style="float:left">selected all</span><span style="float:right;" class="caret"></span></button>
```